# Facebook chat can't work in Smack API with Android

Tags: android, api, smack

I am developing chat client for my app. Now I am testing it on Gtalk, Facebook, Yahoo. I am using Smack api for that. I am now successfully tested it on Gtalk. But in case of Facebook I got error:

```
 01-13 10:53:05.938: INFO/XMPPClient(389): [SettingsDialog] Connected to chat.facebook.com
01-13 10:53:07.178: ERROR/XMPPClient(389): [SettingsDialog] Failed to log in as chikka0305@chat.facebook.com
01-13 10:53:07.178: ERROR/XMPPClient(389): SASL authentication failed using mechanism DIGEST-MD5:
```

As you can see I can connect but can't login. I already saw same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3750547/facing-problem-using-smack-on-android but answer of that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my problem.it si perfectly work with asmack-issue 15.jar.and you have to set:  `connConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);`

---

and you have to set write username only without @chat.facebook.com

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in this site:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat

You can see the following excerpt from this site.

```
Authenticating with Username/Password
```

The DIGEST-MD5 SASL mechanism is available to support traditional XMPP or multi-protocol IM clients that are not customized for (or even aware of) Facebook. This mechanism requires prompting the user for his or her password; therefore, it should only be used when necessary. In particular, it MUST NOT be used for any client that:

Proxies the XMPP connection (the connection must be directly from the user's computer to Facebook).
        Reports messages or any other information about user activity to a third party (including the client developer).
        Integrates with Facebook, or has a Facebook Application ID.

If your application does any of the above, you must use Facebook Platform authentication instead.

The user's Jabber ID is simply his or her Facebook user name with @chat.facebook.com appended. A user must have a Facebook username to use DIGEST-MD5. After the user gets his or her username, he or she must log out of and into Facebook once for us to store the special hash of the password.

If your application falls in any one of the case, then it may not work

Comment: i have tries that once i login and logout from my fb.and it work one time but when now i am trying again it gives me same exception as above.have u any idea abt this.

Comment: how you are connecting to facebook? using steps described in the link?

Comment: i am actually using smack api for it

Comment: this is what mentioned in the documentation.The user's Jabber ID is simply his or her Facebook user name with @chat.facebook.com appended. A user must have a Facebook username to use DIGEST-MD5. After the user gets his or her username, he or she must log out of and into Facebook once for us to store the special hash of the password.

Comment: Facebook support a custom SASL mechanism called X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM that allows clients to connect to chat using Facebook authentication. This mechanism is preferred for any application that is oriented toward social media in general or Facebook in particular, especially applications that are already integrated with Facebook Platform.

In order to connect using this mechanism, the user must first log in to your application and grant the xmpp_login extended permission.

Comment: how can i grant that permission u are talking abt?

Comment: please check this link.it is talking about the permission.http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/.Also please check this link.http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions

Comment: i knw that permission.but how can i get that permission programatically..have u any idea abt that?thnx for ur quick comments.

Comment: The above link talks about that what are the permissions and how to use it along with an example.For example the code https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
    client_id=...&
    redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/callback&
    scope=user_photos,user_videos,publish_stream is talking about getting the permission for user_videos.similary in your case, you need to construct url with xmpp_login authentication.you need to add this along with your url.Hope this will be clear to you.